# Mysterious fopen() issue

Tags: c, debugging, fopen

Hi I'm using VSCode to code C program under Ubuntu:

Here is the full code (it doesn't do what the top comment says, it is only supposed to just print out the last line to `stdout` but the issue discussed here has nothing to do with its functionality):

```c
/*
    Usage: ./reverse [input] [output]

    Algorithm:
    Builds a linked list of strings, each for a line in [input],
    and then walk the nodes backward to build the [output]
*/

#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./reverse [filename]\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // breakpoint set at next line
    char* filename = argv[1];
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file %s\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // StackOverflow users please ignore the rest of the code
    // fseek() to the end of file and move back to find EOL
    int64_t offset = 1;
    int64_t offsetNextEOL = 0;
    int64_t offsetThisEOL = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (fseek(fp, -offset, SEEK_END) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fseek() error\n");
        }
        else {
            char ch = fgetc(fp);
            if (ch == '\n') {
                // print the last line to stdout
                offsetThisEOL = ftell(fp);
                if (offsetNextEOL < offsetThisEOL) {
                    // We just found the last EOL so print everything from it to EOF
                    if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "fseek() error\n");
                    }
                    int64_t offsetEOF = ftell(fp);
                    int64_t offsetDiff = offsetEOF - offsetThisEOL;
                    // Now seek back to offsetThisEOL and start print
                    if (fseek(fp, -offsetThisEOL, SEEK_END) != 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "fseek() error\n");
                    }
                    for (int64_t i = 0; i < offsetDiff; i++) {
                        printf("%c", fgetc(fp));
                    }
                    // For the last line, no need to print EOL

                    // We just found the last EOL so need to set up offsetNextEOL
                    offsetNextEOL = offsetThisEOL;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        offset++;
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The folder structure looks like this (all files in same folder):

```
-os
  -.vscode
  -utils
    reverse.c
    reverse
    reverse.txt
```

Here is the launch.json:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/utils/reverse",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/utils",
        "args": ["reverse.txt"],
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I setup a breakpoint at the line:

```
char* filename = argv[1];
```

Judging from the debugger, there is something wrong with the `fopen()` function. What is really frustrating is that the debugger just flashes three times when I "Step in" and didn't show anything particular before exiting with code 0. I figured there must be something wrong with the path but couldn't figure out.

What went wrong?

Comment: _"What went wrong?"_ - How do you know something went wrong?

Comment: Tangential — The square brackets around the filename argument in the usage message are wrong.  They indicate that the file name is optional, but your test for `argc != 2` shows that it is mandatory.

Comment: Which debugger? I assume `gdb`. I [also] assume that you're setting the breakpoint and then doing `run`. We want to see the arguments passed to the program. Are you launching the program in the _correct_ directory? That is, if the input file is in (e.g.) `/foo/bar/input.txt`, and you invoke with `gdb /path/to/myprogram input.txt`, are starting the program with a current directory of `/foo/bar`? What happens if you use the full path (e.g. `gdb /path/to/myprogram /foo/bar/input.txt`)?

Comment: What is the `#include "stdio.h"`? Does *that* contain defective functions? Why isn't it `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: If you don't explain what the problem is we can only guess.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The debugger just flashes three times when I step into that `fopen()` line and then exit with code 0. I think that's pretty wrong, either `fp` is not NULL and the program continues to execute, or it is NULL and got caught by the next block. Not sure why it does that. BTW I just added a `printf` of `errno` after the `fopen()` and it shows 0 which means no error I think? If that's the case why the debugger does not step into further?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks I didn't know that, that should be mandatory (btw the debugger did include that)

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm using `vscode` to debug the program with the `launch.json` as configuration. I guess part of the problem is that I don't know exactly how vscode works so this is partly a vscode question too. I can use `gdb` to manually debug the program too, let me work on it and get back in a few minutes.

Comment: Do you have the debug-version + source of the standard library installed?

Comment: @CraigEstey I used `gdb` to debug this. I modified the program to make it work (but you will see that it still has issue in gdb so I didn't update the original post). In the terminal I first `cd` into the folder this program lives in (reverse.c, reverse and reverse.txt in the same folder), then I run `gdb reverse`, -> `set args reverse.txt` -> `break reverse.c:21` to break at the line `FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r")` -> `step` and `gdb` shows an error: `offsetNextEOL = offsetThisEOL;`, so I figured there is something wrong with `filename` in debugging but not when I run the program.

Comment: If you don't have the debug-version of the standard library installed, stepping into `fopen` may not be possible. So, do you have that installed?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry I don't quite understand. Do you mean the source `.c` file of the standard library? I don't think so because when the debugger was stuck in `fopen()` line I tried to double click to get into the source code, which is the source code for `fopen()` I think, and VSCode told me I don't have the code. I think it's definitely helpful to have the code but still it doesn't explain why the debugger doesn't continue stepping into the rest of the program (given that `fp` is indeed valid).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh I see, I'll get that installed. Didn't know about that's going to break the step in process.

Comment: The compiler can't easily help with the format of a usage message, but the normal convention is: • use square brackets (`[optional]`) around optional items; • use curly brackets (`{choose|one}`) around alternatives where one must be selected; use ellipsis (triple dots, `...`) carefully to indicate optional repetition (1 or more).  For example: `Usage: prog1 [filename ...]` indicates that `prog1` accepts 0 or more filename arguments; by inference, it probably reads standard input when no names are given. Whereas: `Usage: prog2 filename ...` indicates that `prog2` requires one or more filenames.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping. I finally decided to just use "Step Over" to skip all library code. Still not sure how to make VSCode recognize library source code, and not sure whether I have those installed (where do I check?), but it fixed the debugger issue at least.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the file you are trying to open is not in the directory with the exe.  Ie the cwd is not the source directory.

## update

I see by your comments, you are still having problems.  I have reproduced your code in vscode.

I'll detail my setup for you.  (I'm on osx, but it should not matter.)

### Directory Structure

```
~/progs/reverse
         - .vsode/
                - launch.json - This is the setup for the debugger to run with an input file name as a program argument.
                - tasks.json - This is the file which tells how to run and compile the code.
         - input.txt A simple input text file.
         - reverse.  The binary built from your source.
         - reverse.cpp Your original source unedited.
         - reverse.dSYM/ a directory containing debug symbols. It will be created for you.
```

### tasks.json

This file was created by selecting the source, then clicking on the arrow in top right of the vscode.

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

### launch.json

This file was created intially by clicking on the top right arrow as the launch.json, but using the pull down to select debug. It creates a barebone file.  I supplemented it with the osx c++ file as provided by the help document here. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac
Afterwards, I modified the `args` entry to specify `input.txt`.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
        "name": "C/C++: clang++ build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": ["input.txt"],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Results

Afterwards, I ran the code and debugged the code.  In the debug case, since I modified it to use the input text file as a program argument, it ran however did not generate any output.  I did not debug your code completely, but I did notice:

- the filename on line 21 is correct
- the file is opened correctly on 22
- The seek to the end is correct and the last character is read correctly.
- None of the two fprintf lines or the one printf line hit when a breakpoint it set.

It looks like you are opening the file for read, are reading it, but your logic in the loop is wrong.

Comment: But the code checks the result of `fopen`.

Comment: Hi it is in the same directory. I also think `fopen()` actually works as I `printf` the `errno` and it prints 0. I actually made the program do what it is intended to do (print lines backwards) but the issue described in the original question persists so I'm keeping it open.